Did US troops insist on segregation in British pubs?
Can anyone refresh my memory on this? Wikipedia is no help, as I cannot remember the name of the incident, and any search terms would be too wide.
I understand it involved attempts by USA troops to insist that only white servicemen were served in the public houses. The British were not happy about this - I believe, but am not certain, that some landlords responded by posting "Black Only" signs.
Matters came to a head with violent disorder, presumably between the Americans and British. I'm scant on details, but I believe it is known as the Battle of X Y.

There is a Nevil Shute novel, The Chequer Board, based in part on this.

It wasn't just in Britain, and it wasn't just an objection to American Blacks. See the Battle of Manners Street, where the Yanks were upset at New Zealand Maori soldiers being served in a New Zealand hotel.

@kimchilover Many thanks for the Shute recommendation, just finished it, very interesting from a social history pov!

It should be the battle of Bamber Bridge.
The description of the incident does not link it directly to the British allowing black soldiers into the pubs, but it did happen in the same town.

You might like to use this as a source: https://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ww2peopleswar/stories/85/a3677385.shtml

The episode Killing Time from Series 6 of the British TV drama Foyle's War features Foyle opposing a segregation order that the Americans wanted imposing.

There is no indication that the incident was due to segregation in the pubs. Military police wanted to punish a unit for being out of uniform, and shots started to be fired after a drunken member of that unit physically assaulted the MP.

It's the Battle of Bamber Bridge, but also Constantine v Imperial Hotels Ltd is of interest as to where British law and sympathies lay.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

another way to say that is that links alone are discouraged on most if not all SE sites -  include the important information here and have the link as evidence

After following the link and reading the wiki page, I concur that Constantine vs Imperial Hotels Ltd is a good answer to this question. Please include an explanation and quotes in the body of your answer so that future readers can be convinced too and upvote your answer, and only need to click on the link if they want to learn even more about it.
